# How to display the images from a mysql database? When I tried to display images, its showing only the name of that images

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to retrieve images from mysql table. Now I am getting only the images icons only. Please help me to solve this.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addproduct");
echo "<table border='1'>
        <thead>
            <th>PRODUCT</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>QUANTITY</th>
            <th>IMAGE</th>
        </thead>";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['addProduct']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['quantity']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['price']."</td>";
        //header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        //echo $row['image'];
        //echo "<td><img src=".$row['image']."</td>";
        echo "<td> <img src=" . $row['image'] . "></td>";
            //header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Do you have a folder / directory / catalog for images? If so, you need to build a full path like `'images/' . $row['image']`.

Comment: Where do you store images? In database or storing them in a folder? Looks like you are storing images in a folder and the names are stored in database. Please explain.

Comment: Would you like to help us out by telling us what the full path for your image is?

Answer (score 2):

What will you see if you echo this
`$row['image']` ?

do you see image URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
<img src=<?php echo $row['image']; ?> width="200" height="180">
```

I have assumed that `$row['image']` contains the path of the image.

Comment: no idea mate, but i'd say it's because setting the width and height through attributes, which is so obsolete nowadays.

Comment: I know we can do it using css but there is no harm in it ?? If it was so obsolete then why it was not removed from HTML5. 
According to the HTML 5 specification: The width and height attributes on img ... may be specified to give the dimensions of the visual content of the element.

Comment: it's not BAD, and it's a quick and easy solution for very small projects, that's why (i imagine) it hasn't been removed. On larger scale projects however, having image sizes in markup quickly becomes hard to maintain. This is a polemic however, and for the record it wasn't me with the downvote - i don't have enough points for that. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Yup i know that. I was just expressing my view.Btw, You're right Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Where did you upload your image? In a folder or in database? if you are uploading image in folder then can you check your field or give the relative path to img src tag

Comment: when question is not clear please do not post answers

Comment: How do you know where is the image?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the path `$_SERVER` [$_SERVER Link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
 $image_path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/your path/".$row['image'];
 echo "<td> <img src=" . $image_path . "></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the path is correct. This will work:

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addproduct");
    echo "<table border='1'>
            <thead>
                <th>PRODUCT</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th>QUANTITY</th>
                <th>IMAGE</th>
            </thead>";
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['addProduct']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['quantity']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['price']."</td>";
            //header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            //echo $row['image'];
            //echo "<td><img src=".$row['image']."</td>";
            echo "<td> <img src="/. $row['image'] . "></td>";
                //header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            echo "</tr>";   
        }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   echo "<td><img src='image/".$row['image']."' height=200px width=200px /></td>";
```

added

`image/` as your images folder.